# How do I verify if a series of rake tasks ran correctly? Or, what alternatives are there to rake

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, rake

Somebody has asked a similar question here:

https://github.com/jimweirich/rake/issues/257

The answer from the maintainer was:

```
I am going to reject this since it allows you to use tasks in non-rake-like ways.
```

So what are the correct way of using rake if a task depends of other tasks.

```
task 'succeed' => ['db:drop','stats'] do something end
```

displays results of stats even if Postgres threw an error and db:drop failded because of active connections.

If rake is not suitable for system maintenace, what tools should I use?
I need to be able to run a backup of a database, then do some tests, then drop the database and finally restore from backup.

to hel you understand my problem look at folowing fragment

```
namespace :experiment do
  desc "TODO"
  task 'succeed' => ['stopme', 'stats'] do
    puts 'this and stats task should not run'
  end

  desc "TODO"
  task stopme: :environment do
    Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke
  end
end
```

Comment: Isn't it better to do your experimentations on the backup copy itself? Then you don't need to restore the backup and also your users' data which was created when you was messing with the DB won't be lost.

Comment: @EugZol - no,  because we need to go back to originally saved data and run other tests

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can invoke tasks manually like that:

```
task :stats => :environment do
  Rake::Task['db:drop'].invoke rescue nil
  # do something
end
```

Comment: What was the error message? Probably that was because you should load environment – I'm updating my answer.

Comment: The rake task tries to drop the database, then displays lots of backtrace and 'Couldn't drop db_development'. Then it dispalys output of rake stats. and finally is says 'this and stats task should not run'